# converting into custom objects Swift

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am kind of new in Swift,
I extended SCNNode and tried to cast with another SCNNode but its fails with error

"Could not cast value of type 'SCNNode'  to VirtualObject"

```
class VirtualObject: SCNNode {}
```

Create an object:

```
  var nodeModel =  VirtualObject()
```

Apply Casting (the statement returns an SCNNode):

```
self.nodeModel =  (modelScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: self.nodeName, recursively: true) 
as! VirtualObject
```

This result is an error:
"Could not cast value of type 'SCNNode' to VirtualObject"

can anyone guide me here?

Thanks

Comment: Casting is just a way to tell the compiler what kind of object you are using in cases where it can't know on its own.  It doesn't do any kind of conversion, if that's what you're attempting.

Comment: (Also, there's no need to assign a `VirtualObject()` to your variable if you're immediately going to replace it with a different assignment.)

Comment: Adding to what Phillip Mills said, `childNode(withName:recursively:)` is returning the specified node in the tree. Unless that node is already a `VirtualObject`, you won’t be able to cast it to a `VirtualObject`.

Comment: Since `VirtualObject` inherits from `SCNNode` the cast will always fail, because `SCNNode` is not necessarily a `VirtualObject`.